# Select item(s) from one array of objects and store them in the other

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

### Challenge

I'm trying to select a subset of items from object A to store it in object B. Seems like a very simple task, but for some reason the result is not what I'm expecting. I select 1 item from object A and want to store it in a particular index of object B:

`fselection.categories[cindex].name = categories[cindex].name;`

However, the selected item from object A is stored in every index of object B, not only at the `cindex`. See below MWE.

I tried to work around the issue by writing a plain old for-loop, but also that doesn't resolve it. What is more, this time, object A is filled with empty strings in every position?

```
for(i=0;i<fselection.categories.length;i++){
    console.log(i);
    if(i === cindex){
        fselection.categories[i].name = categories[i].name;
    } else {
        fselection.categories[i].name = "";
    }
}
```

Very strange, no?

### Expected outcome

The expected outcome is to have `fselection.categories[i].name` populated with 1 element from `categories`, namely `fselection.categories[i].name`

### MWE

What's the flow?

1. Load the page
2. Bring up the console - it will show you the instantiated arrays of objects
3. Click the button on the page to see the result in the console

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>...</title>

  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var i,j,k,l,m,n;
    var categories;
    var fselection;

    function init() {

        categories = [{
                name: "A"
            },{
                name: "B"
            },{
                name: "C"
            },{
                name: "D",
                subcategories: [
                    {
                        name: "a"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "b"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "c"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "d"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "e"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "f"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "g"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "h"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "i"
                    }
                ]
            },{
                name: "E",
                subcategories: [
                    {
                        name: "a"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "b"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "c"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "d"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "e"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "f"
                    }
                ]
            },{
                name: "F"
            },{
                name: "G"
            },{
                name: "H"
            }
        ]

        console.log("Instantiated - Cat:")
        console.log(categories);

        //instantiate object
        fselection = JSON.parse('{ "categories": [] }');
        var initcat = JSON.parse('{ "name": "", "subcategories": [] }');
        for(i=0;i<categories.length;i++){
            fselection.categories.push(initcat);
        }
        console.log("Instantiated - Sel:")
        console.log(fselection)
        
    }

    function exec() {

        cindex = 4; //hardcoded for the example
        console.log("Instantiated - Sel:")
        console.log(fselection);
        console.log(fselection.categories[cindex].name)
        console.log(categories[cindex].name)
        fselection.categories[cindex].name = categories[cindex].name;
        console.log("Populated - Sel:")
        console.log(fselection)

    }
        
    </script>

</head>
<style>
</style>

<body onload="init()">
    <button id="myBtn" onclick="exec()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add the data, you have and the data you want and what should happen.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for looking into my question. I want to copy 1 item from categories[cindex].name into fselection.categories[cindex].name, nothing more, nothing less, based on the provided object containing the categories A, B, C, ... and subcategories a, b,c ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your snippet, you populate fselection.categories with this code:

```
var initcat = JSON.parse('{ "name": "", "subcategories": [] }');
for(i=0;i<categories.length;i++){
    fselection.categories.push(initcat);
}
```

The result is that every element of fselection.categories is a reference to the same object (initcat). If you alter a property of that object, it will appear to "change everywhere". If you do something more like:

```
for (i=0;i<categories.length;i++) {
    fselection.categories.push(JSON.parse('{ "name": "", "subcategories": [] }'));
}
```

then each element will be an independent object, and therefore independently alterable.